# how can an eigenvector represent an eigenface?

Tags: pca, eigenvector

I'm using python and the Olivetti dataset (with a lot of 64x64 grayscale face images).

I'm creating a matrix 20x4096, where each line is a sample (I chose 20 samples to be the training set) and each column is a value between 0 and 255, representing all the 64x64 pixels.

After doing PCA in this matrix, I get something about 10 eigenvectors (with 4096 slots each).

The eigenvectors are all normalized (meaning their length is 1). How can an eigenvector represent an eigenface? All its values are something around 0.001 or so.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to visualise which image features are represented by each eigenvector, you can just plot the weight loadings as a heatmap.

Assuming you used scikit-learn to perform PCA, you can do this with following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(pca.components_[i].reshape(64,64),cmap=”gray”)
```

Where `pca` is your fitted PCA() variable and `i` is the ith principal component from the eigenvector matrix.